# How to Test Site Performance in Asia

Tags: performance

I'm located in the US and need to test site performance for Asian audiences. Any provide help on how I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google 'site performance test' and you will find a number of options for testing responsiveness of your website from various locations around the world.  I have used Keynote in the past and found it worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to simulate low bandwitch. In menu there is option Rules|Performance|Simulate modem speeds.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a performance test tool, like [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). These tools support remote test execution, so you can make the test case on your local machine and run it later from a remote server, in Asia.

To get a server in Asia, you can try [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/). They have instances in Singapore and Tokyo.